# Which NLP applications are based on recurrent neural networks?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, applications

Some of the NLP applications taken from this link [NLP Applications](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-nlp-top-10-applications-to-know-b2c80bd428cb):

- Machine Translation
- Speech Recognition
- Sentiment Analysis
- Question Answering
- Automatic Summarization
- Chatbots
- Market Intelligence
- Text Classification
- Character Recognition
- Spell Check

Which are the NLP applications that supports recurrent neural network?

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition and Character recognition are not part of NLP. Everything else on your list can in principle be done with RNNs. But the field is quickly moving towards using [transformers](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need.pdf).

Comment: I wanted just to add that RNN can also be used for speech recognition, even if it is not an NLP task.

Comment: Why aren't speech recognition and character recognition part of NLP? Also, in principle, many things can be done, so it may be useful to show that RNNs have already been used to solve the specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Other tasks that RNNs are effective at solving are time-series predictions or other sequence predictions that aren’t image or tabular based.